# .htaccess RewriteRule and FallbackResource don't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm testing stuff on localhost, and this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC,L]
FallbackResource error.php
```

in my root directory (/var/www). It just doesn't work. I've already set the "AllowOverride All" in the configuration file: if I put garbage in .htaccess file I get an internal server error (and not a 404), meaning (I think) that the AllowOverride is set properly.
I get "Module rewrite already enabled" if I give "a2enmod rewrite" and, of course, I restarted apache.
Any suggestion? I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I found that this error occured only when I tried to access an address with the .php extension.  If for example I tried to access test.mydomain.com/home.php, I would get a 404 error.  If, however, I tried to access test.mydomain.com/home.html, I had no problem.  So I thought it had to do with php interfering with the redirection.

Turns out I had to comment out the following line in my public_html .htaccess file:

```
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
```

After that, I could access files in the webroot folder.